# calibration of the posterior probabilities

Tags: r, algorithm, statistics, probability, calibration

currently i work on calibration of probability. i use the calibration approach, called `rescaling algorithm` - the source http://lem.cnrs.fr/Portals/2/actus/DP_201106.pdf (page 7).

the algorithm i wrote is:

```
rescaling_fun = function(x, y, z) {

    P_korg  = z # yhat_test_prob$BAD

    P_k_C1  = sum(as.numeric(y) - 1)/length(y) # testset$BAD
    P_kt_C1 = sum(as.numeric(x) - 1)/length(x) # trainset$BAD
    P_k_C0  = sum(abs(as.numeric(y) - 2))/length(y)
    P_kt_C0 = sum(abs(as.numeric(x) - 2))/length(x)

    P_new <- ((P_k_C1/P_kt_C1) * P_korg)/((P_k_C0/P_k_C0) * (1 - P_korg) + (P_k_C0/P_k_C1) * (P_korg))

  return(P_new)
}
```

the input values are:

```
1. x - train_set$BAD (actuals of `train set`)
2. y - test_set$BAD (actuals of `test set`)
3. z - yhat_test_prob$BAD (prediction on `test set`)
```

the problem - the result values are not within range of `0` and `1`. Could you please help to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas to obtain probs (`P_k_C1` ...) need to be modified. For example, according to the paper, y is a binary variable (0, 1) and the formula is `sum(y - 1)/length(y)` which is most likely to be negative - it converts y values to be -1 or 0, followed by adding them. I consider it should be `(sum(y)-1)/length(y)`. Below is an example.

```
set.seed(1237)
y <- sample(0:1, 10, replace = T)
y
[1] 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1
# it must be negative as it is sum(y - 1) - y is 0 or 1
sum(as.numeric(y) - 1)/length(y)
[1] -0.5
# modification 
(sum(as.numeric(y)) - 1)/length(y)
[1] 0.4
```

Comment: Jaehyeon, thank u for the quick answer. I found the mistake, the P_new, must be ((P_k_C1/P_kt_C1) * P_korg)/((P_k_C0/P_kt_C0) * (1 - P_korg) + (P_k_C1/P_kt_C1) * (P_korg)), this was the first mistake. then I used ur modification to P_k_c1, P_kt_c1, P_k_c0 and P_kt_c0, and indeed, almost all output values are in a range of 0 and 1, but not all of them, maybe I need to modify only y?

Comment: I have tried all possible combinations, and it seems that with / without this modification the results are within 0 and 1. but there is a model (WEKAModelAdditiveRegression) and it's predictions can be negative (i.e. -0,765) or higher than 1 (i.e. 1,235), maybe it should be standardtized first? to get its prediction to a range of 0 and 1?

Comment: I'm not aware of WEKAModelAdditiveRegression and thus can't answer specifically. In general, when a binary response enters into a regression model (including generalized additive model (GAM)), it can be lower than 0 or greater than 1. Logistic regression is an exception as its link function prevents that. In R, the gam package fits GAM and the function `gam()` seems to have an argument to select a link function like `glm()`

Comment: thank u for the answer! ok, it seems that i have to normalize the output values, if they can be more than 1 or less than 0. maybe u can help me on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29954519/generalized-additive-models-for-calibration :D

Comment: If you want to normalize a binary response, you may search the binomial canonical link function of GLM as it seems to be applied to GAM as well. Note, however, that those packages (gam, mgcv) follow the frequentist approach while the package seems to talk about the Bayesian approach, which I'm not well aware of.