# Generalized additive models for calibration

Tags: r, statistics, probability, prediction, calibration

I work on calibration of probabilities. I'm using a probability mapping approach called [generalized additive models](http://lem.cnrs.fr/Portals/2/actus/DP_201106.pdf).

The algorithm I wrote is:

```
probMapping = function(x, y, datax, datay) {

    if(length(x) < length(y))stop("train smaller than test")
    if(length(datax) < length(datay))stop("train smaller than test")

    datax$prob = x # trainset: data and raw probabilities
    datay$prob = y # testset: data and raw probabilities

    prob_map = gam(Target ~ prob, data = datax, familiy = binomial, trace = TRUE)
    prob_map_prob = predict(prob_map, newdata = datay, type = "prob")

  # return(str(datax))
  return(prob_map_prob)
}
```

The package I'm using is `mgcv`.

1. x - prediction on `train` dataset
2. y - prediction on `test` dataset
3. datax - `traindata`
4. datay - `testdata`

Problems:

1. The output values are not between 0 and 1
2. I get the following warning message:

   ```
   In predict.gam(prob_map, newdata = datay, type = "prob") :
   Unknown type, reset to terms.
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning is telling you that `predict.gam` doesn't recognize the value you passed to the `type` parameter. Since it didn't understand, it decided to use the default value of `type`, which is `"terms"`.

Note that `predict.gam` with `type="terms"` returns information about the model terms, *not* probabilties. Hence the output values are not between 0 and 1.

For more information about `mgcv::predict.gam`, take a look [here](http://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/mgcv/functions/predict.gam.html).

Comment: hey Alex, thank u very much for your answer! two points i have learned: i) type must be "response", ii) in fitting there is a mistake, i wrote "familiy" - must be "family". I am sorry for that. Alex, could u please also comment on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948919/calibration-of-the-posterior-probabilities - i have tried the answer provided, but the result is still not between 0 and 1